# Language Server not getting onDidSave or onDidOpenTextDocument

Tags: vscode-extensions

I am writing an extension for vscode that will run a linter against an esoteric language.  I want the extension to automatically determine which files are open in vscode and lint those files immediately, then lint any file that gets saved in vscode.

Thus far, I've only been able to detect file changes with `onDidChangeWatchedFiles()`.  This doesn't meet my needs because it detects changes in files that are not open by vscode, and when the extension starts it doesn't give me a list of already opened files.

As best as I can tell, I should be able to simply call `documents.onDidSave((event) => {...});`, however my listener is never called.  I've also tried with `documents.onWillSave()` and `connection.onDidOpenTextDocument()`.

Does anyone know how I can get a list of open files? And does anyone know how to listen to save events?

I wonder if it's because my `TextDocuments` store isn't being populated with documents?

My `server.ts` file is:

```
import {
    createConnection,
    TextDocuments,
    ProposedFeatures,
    InitializeParams,
    TextDocumentSyncKind,
    InitializeResult,
} from 'vscode-languageserver/node';

import {
    TextDocument
} from 'vscode-languageserver-textdocument';
import { URI } from 'vscode-uri';
import { lint } from './lint';

// Create a connection for the server, using Node's IPC as a transport.
// Also include all preview / proposed LSP features.
const connection = createConnection(ProposedFeatures.all);

// Create a simple text document manager.
const documents: TextDocuments<TextDocument> = new TextDocuments(TextDocument);

connection.onInitialize((params: InitializeParams) => {
    const result: InitializeResult = {
        capabilities: {
            textDocumentSync: TextDocumentSyncKind.Incremental,
            diagnosticProvider: {
                interFileDependencies: false,
                workspaceDiagnostics: false,

            }
        }
    };
    return result;
});

connection.onDidChangeWatchedFiles(change => {
    // Monitored files have change in VSCode
    connection.console.log('We received a file change event');
    const uri = URI.parse(change.changes[0].uri);
    
    lint(uri.fsPath).then(diagnostics => {
        connection.sendDiagnostics({uri: change.changes[0].uri, diagnostics});
    });
});

documents.onWillSave((event) => {
    connection.console.log("here");
});
documents.onDidSave((event) => {
    connection.console.log("there");
});
connection.onDidOpenTextDocument((event) => {
    connection.console.log("everywhere");
});

// Make the text document manager listen on the connection
// for open, change and close text document events
documents.listen(connection);

// Listen on the connection
connection.listen();
```